# Youtube video loads from ISP, not Google

Tags: youtube, cache, isp

Using Wireshark, I noticed that the Youtube video I was watching had the source address of my ISP, not Google. Does this mean my ISP is using Google Cache and loading all video from there? If so, what sort of information does this leak to my ISP?

Comment: What you have discovered does mean your information is leaking to your ISP.  It also means more then likely the ISP your connected to requires the use of a proxy to work, this means more then likely, all secure content isn't actually secure.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's not necessarily the case – Google Cache redirects seem to be mostly GeoDNS-based.

Comment: Maybe the guys over at Information Security might get you better answers. Is it TLS traffic? If yes what does the cert say?

Comment: @paradoxon Yes, it's TLS. The cert belongs Google. CA is GeoTrust Global.

Comment: @black - That is the correct certificate for Google.com, which means, your ISP cannot view any traffic between your browser and google.com

Comment: @Ramhound So does this mean my ISP is simply rewriting the source IP? I notice that even when my connection is generally slow, youtube videos load quickly. Is that due to Google Cache?

Comment: @black - It means you are not interrupting what Wireshark is displaying correctly.